# optimize function that reads and mirrors a half numpy matrix

Tags: python, optimization

I have a text file that has some values of a matrix, but it just has half of the values of it, like this:

```
1.         1.         0.01      
2.         1.         0.052145
2.         2.         0.045      
3.         1.         0.054521
3.         2.         0.05424
3.         3.         0.05459898
```

the first two columns are referent to matrix (x,y) position, and the last one, the value it has. the first two values might be, actually, value-1.

I made a `function` that reads the file and mirrors these values to a full matrix:

```
def expand_mirror_matrix(matrix_path='data.txt'):
    data = np.loadtxt(matrix_path)
    shape = (int(data[-1][0]), int(data[-1][1]))
    m = np.zeros(shape)

    for d in data:
        x, y, z = int(d[0]), int(d[1]), d[2]
        m[x-1,y-1] = z
        m[shape[0]-x,shape[1]-y]=z
                  
    return m
```

But it has some unnecessary `loops`, like the first and the last, and the `loop` that changes the value of the center of the matrix.

Is there a way of optimizing it? This file actually have thousands of lines, it might be great to downgrade this `loop` execution time.

Comment: Your `expand_mirror_matrix` isn't correct either, if I correctly assume what you're trying to do. The text file contains a triangular matrix you wish to mirror across the diagonal, is that correct? Note that your current code does not output a matrix that contains `0.01` at all despite it being in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want, at least without the mirroring:

```
def expand_mirror_matrix(matrix_path='data.txt'):
    data = np.loadtxt(matrix_path)
    shape = (int(data[-1][0]), int(data[-1][1]))
    xs = data[:,0].astype(int) - 1  # Numpy uses zero-based indexing.
    ys = data[:,1].astype(int) - 1

    m = np.zeros(shape)
    m[(xs, ys)] = data[:,2]
    return m
```

For your example file above this returns:

```
array([[0.01      , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.052145  , 0.045     , 0.        ],
       [0.054521  , 0.05424   , 0.05459898]])
```

If you wish to mirror it you probably want to edit the above function with the following:

```
m[(xs, ys)] = data[:,2]
m[(ys, xs)] = data[:,2]  # Mirrored.
```

The result of that is:

```
array([[0.01      , 0.052145  , 0.054521  ],
       [0.052145  , 0.045     , 0.05424   ],
       [0.054521  , 0.05424   , 0.05459898]])
```

Note that this assumes the matrix is square.